# WGET incompletely spidered the target website

Tags: wget

My idea was to use wget to create a complete list of all the threads of a very big blog (according to the blog itself the total number of threads is 50,000). I used wget in --spider mode to crawl the website and output the urls in a text file. After 1d 3h 3m 3s  wget completed its work but I identified 'only' 9668 files against the 50,000 presented on the website. According to wget 643 links were broken so my first idea was to check whether the missing threads were somehow related with the broken links, but apparently they are not. The blog keeps its threads in folders named after year and month (e.g. /2012/01/name_of_thread.html). Some broken links appeared to refer to folders from which wget downloaded some threads, so I would exclude a blackout on selected folders. Also missing threads (which I located browsing the blog) appeared to be from the same folder from which wget corrently downloaded few other threads.

Where do I start to understand what went wrong?

Comment: If you have control about that site it is much more simpler to take a sql dump. If not sure that you have the permission to download that data?

Comment: No, I haven't control of the website. I just see what is published.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes blog publishing/hosting platforms use unusual robots.txt files, so -e robots=off may be called for.  I had a similar issue crawling a WordPress blog, where strange output was being shaped by robots exclusions - it was somewhat similar to your problem.

Depending on how the blog is structured, you may have better results with a more careful crawl.  If it uses pagination (www.site.com/archive/1/, www.site.com/archive/2/...), you could crawl each page via a for loop and parse the content of each.  This will give you more controlled results, as you can verify and test against a small subset of data (e.g. ten pages of threads at a time) instead of all 50k threads at once.

It's also possible that the site is reporting bad numbers - are you certain that there should be 50k threads?

Comment: No, I am not certain about 50k but I am sure many threads have not been crawled by wget. I could easily found missing threads by browsing the website, I didn't have to search for long, It was actually more difficult to find a thread that was crawled. I tried to crawl some www.site.com/archive/1/ but in that case wget doesn't return any url, probably it can't find any index. I am now having a look at PhpCrawl.